# Generate all possible permutation of multiple lists and access them in python

Tags: python

I have two permuted lists, one of them contains string-keys and other corresponding values:

**list1**

```
('inputData1', 'targetData1')
('inputData1', 'targetData2')
('inputData1', 'targetData3')
('inputData2', 'targetData1')
('inputData2', 'targetData2')
('inputData2', 'targetData3')
...
```

`list2` for corresponding `inputData1`and `targetData1`

**list2**

```
(array([[  30.1678, -173.569 ,  725.724 ],
   [  29.9895, -173.34  ,  725.76  ],
   [  29.9411, -173.111 ,  725.768 ],
   [  29.9306, -173.016 ,  725.98  ],
   [  29.6754, -172.621 ,  725.795 ],
   [  29.5277, -172.274 ,  725.903 ],
   [  29.585 , -171.978 ,  726.111 ],
   [  29.4114, -171.507 ,  726.188 ],
   [  29.3951, -170.947 ,  726.173 ],
   [  29.3577, -170.196 ,  726.384 ],
   [  29.3594, -169.771 ,  726.52  ]]), 
array([[  14.8016, -175.911 ,  779.752 ],
   [  14.7319, -175.483 ,  779.504 ],
   [  14.5022, -175.087 ,  779.388 ],
   [  14.4904, -174.576 ,  779.416 ],
   [  14.4881, -174.058 ,  779.452 ],
   [  14.1612, -173.558 ,  779.459 ],
   [  14.0831, -172.938 ,  779.675 ],
   [  13.9405, -172.117 ,  780.146 ],
   [  13.8627, -171.233 ,  780.568 ],
   [  14.056 , -170.34  ,  780.876 ],
   [  14.1102, -169.477 ,  781.265 ]]))
```

To generate permutations for keys and values, I use `itertools.product()` function:

```
strIdx= []
for strIdx in itertools.product(inputDataNameStrings, targetDataNameStrings):
    print('dataNameIndex_Pairs:', strIdx)

valIdx= []
for valIdxin itertools.product(inputDataValue, targetDataValue):
    print('dataValueIndex_Pairs:\n', self.valIdx)
```

My goal is to get again a permuted output from above permutations and access each item over key:

```
list3=
(('inputData1' [inputData1ValueArray]), ('targetData1' [targetData1ValueArray]))
(('inputData1' [inputData1ValueArray]), ('targetData2' [targetData2ValueArray]))
(('inputData1' [inputData1ValueArray]), ('targetData3' [targetData3ValueArray]))
(('inputData2' [inputData2ValueArray]), ('targetData1' [targetData1ValueArray]))
```

How can I do this?
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: what kind of *object* is `list3`? a tuple of tuple of tuples? Same holds for `list1`. These are not valid Python objects at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want here, but is something like this what your after:

```
list1= [('inputData1', 'targetData1'),
        ('inputData1', 'targetData2'),
        ('inputData1', 'targetData3'),
        ('inputData2', 'targetData1'),
        ('inputData2', 'targetData2'),
        ('inputData2', 'targetData3')]

list2 = [[i] for i in range(len(list1) * 2)]
# [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]]

list2 = [tuple(list2[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(list2), 2)]
# [([0], [1]), ([2], [3]), ([4], [5]), ([6], [7]), ([8], [9]), ([10], [11])]

print([((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) for (x1, x2), (y1, y2) in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(('inputData1', [0]), ('targetData1', [1])), 
 (('inputData1', [2]), ('targetData2', [3])), 
 (('inputData1', [4]), ('targetData3', [5])), 
 (('inputData2', [6]), ('targetData1', [7])), 
 (('inputData2', [8]), ('targetData2', [9])), 
 (('inputData2', [10]), ('targetData3', [11]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't have those variable values so i modified a little , you don't have to modify the list2 if you have those values already defined somewhere :

```
list1=[('inputData1', 'targetData1'),
('inputData1', 'targetData2'),
('inputData1', 'targetData3'),
('inputData2', 'targetData1'),
('inputData2', 'targetData2'),
('inputData2', 'targetData3')]


list2=[['inputData1ValueArray'], ['targetData1ValueArray'],
['inputData1ValueArray'], ['targetData2ValueArray'],
['inputData1ValueArray'], ['targetData3ValueArray'],
['inputData2ValueArray'], ['targetData1ValueArray'],
['inputData2ValueArray'], ['targetData2ValueArray'],
['inputData2ValueArray'], ['targetData3ValueArray']]



final_=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        sub_={}
        if i[0] in j[0]:
            sub_[i[0]]=j[0]
        elif i[1] in j[0]:
            sub_[i[1]]=j[0]
        if sub_:
            final_.append(sub_)

print(final_)
```

output:

```
[{'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'targetData1': 'targetData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'targetData1': 'targetData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'targetData2': 'targetData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'targetData2': 'targetData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData1': 'inputData1ValueArray'}, {'targetData3': 'targetData3ValueArray'}, {'targetData3': 'targetData3ValueArray'}, {'targetData1': 'targetData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'targetData1': 'targetData1ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'targetData2': 'targetData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'targetData2': 'targetData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'targetData3': 'targetData3ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'inputData2': 'inputData2ValueArray'}, {'targetData3': 'targetData3ValueArray'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question, in order give more details over `list2`. If I add your code-block after my two for-loops, the list `final_` is empty. Actually after getting new list, I want to call a function, which takes the pairs as attribute eg. in a for-loop iteratively. such: `do_someting(inputData1, inputData1ValueArray, targetData1, targetData1ValueArray)`